# Stack Push Method Infinite Loop Java

Tags: java, stack, infinite-loop, singly-linked-list

I do not understand why printList() loops infinitely when called. I am attempting to code a stack linked list and print the list without using the built-in stack methods in java. Why is my print method looping infinitely and how do I correct this issue?

```
public class LinkedListStack{
    private String item;
    private Node next;
    private Node top = null;

    public LinkedListStack(){
    }

    public void push(String item){
        top = new Node(item, top);
    }

    public void printList(){
        Node currentNode = top;
        for(currentNode = top; currentNode.getItem()!= null; currentNode = currentNode.getNext()){
            System.out.println(currentNode.getItem());
        }
    }

    public class Node{
        public Node(String newItem, Node nextNode){
            item = newItem;
            next = nextNode;
        }

        public Node(String newItem){
            item = newItem;
            next = null;
        }

        //to set the value of the next field
        public void setNext(Node nextNode){
            next = nextNode;
        }

        //read the value of the next field
        public Node getNext(){
            return(next);
        }

        //to set the value of the item field
        public String setItem(String newItem){
            item = newItem;
            return(item);
        }

        //read the value of the item field
        public String getItem(){
            return(item);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedListStack newList = new LinkedListStack();
        newList.push("hello");
        newList.push("goodbye");
        newList.printList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare "currentNode" in printList() before the loop if you are going to create a local variable with the same name in the loop header?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `item` and `next` are fields of `LinkedListStack` and shared between all `Node` instances. When you create another `Node` and set the item you change *all* nodes. To fix it just move the field declarations to the `Node` inner class.
Beside that, your loop's condition in the `printList` method is wrong: the next node is null, not its item.
Here is a working example:

```
public class LinkedListStack {
    private Node top = null;

    public LinkedListStack() {
    }

    public void push(final String item) {
        top = new Node(item, top);
    }

    public void printList() {
        Node currentNode = top;
        for (currentNode = top; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.getNext()) {
            System.out.println(currentNode.getItem());
        }
    }

    public class Node {
        private String item;
        private Node next;

        public Node(final String newItem, final Node nextNode) {
            item = newItem;
            next = nextNode;
        }

        public Node(final String newItem) {
            item = newItem;
            next = null;
        }

        // to set the value of the next field
        public void setNext(final Node nextNode) {
            next = nextNode;
        }

        // read the value of the next field
        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        // to set the value of the item field
        public String setItem(final String newItem) {
            item = newItem;
            return item;
        }

        // read the value of the item field
        public String getItem() {
            return item;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final LinkedListStack newList = new LinkedListStack();
        newList.push("hello");
        newList.push("goodbye");
        newList.printList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!